# PHP maintain HTTP connection while server downloads file? (WP Upgrade)

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, http, curl

I am trying to perform Core WP Upgrade and the issue I have is that the server takes time to download the update package and doesn't send any response body during this time, so the browser terminates the script (timeout?) which then terminates the PHP script I assume.

A temporary work around I've found is that if I edit core WP files to output some filler text while downloading the file (it's downloaded via cURL using a CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION) then the connection remains alive and the package downloads.

However, the next step is the to unzip the package, which takes sometime and then fails again (browser closes the connection since nothing is received).

Any way to keep the connection alive while the server is performing the upgrade?

Comment: I've never had this problem upgrading WP ever.  Are you just trying to update through the admin panel or is this for a plugin or something you're writing?  Any reason you can't just download from wordpress.org/latest.zip and manually upgrade by uploading the contents of that package over your WP install?  Otherwise, just edit your `php.ini` settings and change `max_execution_time` to something higher.  Error logs may show why it's failing.

Comment: Yes, upgrading core through admin panel default behaviour. No reason I can't do a manual upgrade other than I would like to solve this issue and figure out which server settings are causing it to fail. I've enabled WP debugging and I'm getting NO error whatsoever, it just appears to time out.

Comment: If you feel like it's the browser closing the connection because of a timeout rather than anything on the server, then maybe that means the server is super slow to download.  What browser are you using when it times out?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways you may be able to achieve the desired results. Firstly, you can set a few cURL options; `CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT or CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT_MS` will define the number of seconds (or milliseconds) to wait while trying to connect. `CURLOPT_TIMEOUT or CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS` will define the number of seconds (or milliseconds) for curl to run before closing the connection.

You can also set the max_execution_time in php.ini, which defaults to 30 seconds. It is usually safe to change this periodically to a larger number however I would encourage you to set it back to it's default of 30 seconds once you have finished what you need to do.

You can view further curl options and examples [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php). You can read about changing the max_execution_time through runtime configuration [here](http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php) or through php.ini [here](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.php)

Comment: Hi, these are core WP files, so I'm only editing for debugging purposes, I shouldn't have to change any of them. To clarify the issue, it seems the browser closes the connection while PHP is downloading a large file in the background and not sending any content to the browser. So I need a way to maintain the connection open until PHP has finished executing it's entire script. It would seem this is more of a server config issue?